# is it possible, by code, to find which version of the assembly is used?

Tags: asp.net

I need to know which version of the report viewer control is used on a web server.

If I can find it without asking it would be nice.

Is there a way, by code, to find out which version of the assembly is used on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection you could take a look at the [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) property:

```
var version = Assembly
    .Load("NameOfTheAssembly")
    .GetName()
    .Version;
```

Comment: I need to specify the whole line in the "NameOfTheAssembly", this line: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A, which give me automaticly version 8.0.0.0, I want to know the real version on it.

Comment: @Fredou: you may use Assembly.GetAssembly(aTypeFromYourAssembly.GetType()) instead of Assembly.Load("NameOfTheAssembly").

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var version = typeof (ReportViewer).Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

EDIT:

As I understand you need to know assembly file version. There is a way to find it:

```
var fileVersionAttribute = typeof(ReportViewer).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), true)[0] as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;
var version = fileVersionAttribute.Version;
```

Remember to add error checking.

Comment: return 8.0.0.0 with that one too

Comment: and which version is used on the server?

Comment: this is what I want to know, are they using sp1 or not